# Wordpress ninja form change required attribute on condition

Tags: plugin-ninja-forms

In my ninja form , I have required field . But I want to change that required attribute if the user is not logged in . I have seen ninja form documentaion and tried as they say . Here is what I have tried .

```
function my_filter_function( $data, $field_id ){

  if(!is_user_logged_in()){  
    if( $field_id == 135){
      $data['req'] =0;
    }
  return $data;
  }
}
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_field', 'my_filter_function', 10, 2 );
```

But it doesn't work . When I submit the form it says that field is required .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a way to accomplish this , The solution to problem is to call update the field setting function

```
function ninja_forms_change_required_field(){
  add_action( 'ninja_forms_before_pre_process', 'ninja_forms_code' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'ninja_forms_change_required_field' );
function ninja_forms_code(){
  global $ninja_forms_processing;
  if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $data['req'] = '0';
        $ninja_forms_processing->update_field_settings(135, $data);
  }
}
```

If a field is required then then **$data['req'] = '1'**